# How can we get Relay to work in production with NextJS?

Tags: next.js, relay

I have a NextJS project using Relay. I have it working fine in development, but when I build, it is building static pages and is trying to access my GraphQL server (in dev it is pointed to https://localhost:3000/api/graphql), but I don't want it to since it should be a dynamic page.

With that, I also can't seem to get SSR working with Relay since a lot of functionality in Relay requires hooks and we can't use hooks in non React components (like getServerSideProps()). I got as far as using loadQuery from Relay in getServerSideProps but now my issue is that I need to get the Relay environment somehow, but again, can't use getRelayEnvironment() in there either. I import it from the createRelayEnvironment file but then I'm not using my App's environment (RelayEnvironmentProvider at the root of my App).

Anyone have success with using Relay in NextJS?

Comment: _"when I build, it is building static pages"_ - are all your pages using `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: I was not, so that explains why it was trying to build static, but I found the solution that worked for me. Not sure how I missed this seeing it was right in the [NextJS examples on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-relay-modern)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this, but I followed along with [NextJS's example for using Relay Modern](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-relay-modern) on GitHub.

I didn't do everything the same - I don't have a .babelrc file, for example, because that info is in the next.config.js file (thanks to [NextJS 12.1](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1)).

What I really used from here was how they were starting and using relay in their [relay.js file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-relay-modern/lib/relay.js). Then I used that in a `getServerSideProps` function in my page just like how they did in their [index.js file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-relay-modern/pages/index.js).